# Does the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n $$

converge? I was trying to use this as a convergent majorant for proving convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {\ln(n)} n $$ but I'm not sure if that would work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It ($\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$) doesn't converge since $(-1)^n$ does not go to $0$. Remember that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ can only converge if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. That series is an interesting series called Grandi's series though, and you can find more information about it at [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series).

Comment: Suppose it did. What do you imagine it would convergent to?

Comment: Second: You can prove convergence using a majorant, only if the proposed majorant is positive.

Comment: @MJD I figured maybe 1 or $ 0$, but I'm not really convinced of it (hence my question here).

Comment: Did you try to calculate the partial sums of this series? No need to use any theorem to prove that this series does not converge. Just use definition.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Did not. However, I see what you mean now: it is alternating between -1 and 0, so indeed it does not converge.

Comment: For the series to converge to zero, there must come a term after which it is always within $\epsilon$ of zero, for any given $\epsilon$. At what point does this series get within $\frac12$ of zero and stay there?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies! It's very clear to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}$ means

You get $-1 + 1 -1 + 1...$

Does that converge to a number? Clearly not, it goes back and forth between $-1$ and $0$

A convergent sum will get closer and closer to one particular value, and can in fact get arbitrarily close to that value, which clearly our sum does not.

Answer (score 1):

Given $n\geq 1$, you have that $\frac{\ln n}{n}\geq 0$. Moreover, $n\mapsto \frac{\ln n}{n}$ is a decreasing function, which tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus, you may apply the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) to conclude that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{\ln n}{n}$ converges.